# Get the id of a dynamically added image

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I am using fine uploader 5 plugin to upload images and I need to get the id of an image when it is uploaded.

My code is:

```
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template-gallery">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader qq-gallery" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
        <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
            <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
            <div>Upload a file</div>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
        <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" role="region" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
            <li>
                <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector qq-progress-bar-container">
                    <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <div class="qq-thumbnail-wrapper">
                    <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" id="imageID" qq-max-size="120" qq-server-scale>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">X</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">
                <span class="qq-btn qq-retry-icon" aria-label="Retry"></span>
                Retry
                </button>
                <div class="qq-file-info">
                    <div class="qq-file-name">
                        <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                        <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                    </div>
                    <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                    <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">
                    <span class="qq-btn qq-delete-icon" aria-label="Delete"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-pause-selector qq-upload-pause">
                    <span class="qq-btn qq-pause-icon" aria-label="Pause"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-continue-selector qq-upload-continue">
                    <span class="qq-btn qq-continue-icon" aria-label="Continue"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>
        <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>
        <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <input type="text">
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>
    </div>

</script>
<div id="fine-uploader-gallery"></div>
```

```
$('#fine-uploader-gallery').fineUploader({
    template: 'qq-template-gallery',
});
request: {
        endpoint: 'upload_multiple_images'
    },
    thumbnails: {
        placeholders: {
            waitingPath: '../assets/plugins/jquery.fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
            notAvailablePath: '../assets/plugins/jquery.fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
        }
    },
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
    }
});
```

Please can some one guide me how to get the id of
 img whose id=imgID 
each time when it is added dynamically. Thanks in advance

Comment: which plugin are you using? they might have documented it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the callbacks . Take a look on [their documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/events.html)

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    // options
    callbacks: {
        onUpload: function (id, name) {
        },
        onSubmitted: function (id, name) {
        }
    }
});
```